# how fillup states after select country

Tags: php

I have 2 MYSQL tables, one of them has Countries and fills out the combo box as:

```
  $test_query = "SELECT A.id, country FROM  table_Countries ";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $test_query);

    <select class="country">
        <option value='0'>USA</option>
      <?php       while($tbl = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
          echo "<option value =$tbl[0]>$tbl[1]</option>";
    }

    ?>
      </select>
```

The frist box works just fine, but what I try to do is:
when user selects a country from first box fills the state box from mysql table called states by selected country id above.
basically fill in states according to the selected country

```
 $test_query = "SELECT statename FROM  table_states where country_id= "  how_to_get_id_from_above_box_after_select ;

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $test_query);

    <select class="states">
        <option value='0'>ANY</option>
      <?php       while($tbl = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
          echo "<option value =$tbl[0]>$tbl[0]</option>";
    }

    ?>
      </select>
```

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically fill select field in html and javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31292796/dynamically-fill-select-field-in-html-and-javascript)

Comment: Check https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php on how to send data to your PHP script.